# Docker error : mountpoint not found

Tags: docker

I've got problem running docker on ArchLinux. I pull debian base image, and when i try to launch an interactive bash prompt with that command :

```
# docker run -it debian:latest /bin/bash
```

Docker give me this error :

```
2014/06/24 22:49:11 Error response from daemon: Cannot start container 94d0c07b428c63205390d3b2ac49896038fe27af9c4118d9d25decd8d9201dae: mountpoint not found
```

I'm new with docker, I don't really know what I'm supposed to do.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 11):

Adding this for reference purposes as I had this error message on Wheezy. Doing this

```
apt-get install libcgroup1
```

fixed things for me.

Comment: I needed also `apt-get install cgroupfs-mount cgroup-bin  cgroup-tools` to fix it.

Answer (score 4):

There is some problem with current version of Docker.

Here you can find some comments about similar problem.
https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues/6619

I guess the latest image is broken - I can't run it either.

You can try with ubuntu or debian:stable:)

```
# docker run -it debian:stable /bin/bash
```

or

```
# docker run -it ubuntu /bin/bash
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your kernel is missing some modules that docker needs

run `lxc-checkconfig` and make sure you are not missing anything.

I guess you will find `Multiple /dev/pts instances: missing`.

Just update your kernel and enable all the required modules including user namespaces, cgroup, and support for multiple dev/pts instances

Comment: This fix my problem because I used umount -a before, so the /dev was unmounted too.  Thanks !